# How to relax an RDF graph

Tags: rdf, jena

I want to know if there is a way to relax an RDF graph using Jena. I'm actually using DBpedia spotlight. For example, I have this URI: http://dbpedia.org/resource/Halloween and I generate the RDF Graph for it, but i wonder if there is a way to relax this RDF graph with other resources that may be useful for the user. I'm a beginner in semantic web. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible - just implement a basic shortest-path algorithm, feed in all RDF resources as vertices and all relations as edges, and you're good to go. But can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?  Shortest-path computation (or any sort of graph theory stuff) is not really something that is often used in an RDF context - the fact that RDF can be considered a graph is almost incidental in most cases.

Comment: Actually, the main idea is trying to create rich snippets. So, for example, if the user is searching for the word "Halloween", the result will show everything relative to the concept, if there is a movie which name is "halloween", it will suggest it.